# as.data.frame.H2OFrame deletes rows when they contain a quote

Tags: r, h2o

I am using `h2o` to develop machine learning models. I'm done and have my predictions, now I want to transform my H2OFrame back to a data.frame to do some error analysis.

I tried the `as.data.frame` function to transform my H2OFrame to the standard R data.frame.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
tmp <- data.frame(ngram = c("SIRET:417 653 698",
                            "SIRET:417 653 698 00031",
                            "Sans",
                            "Sans esc.",
                            "Sans esc. jusqu\"au",
                            "Sans esc. jusqu\"au 15.11.2018"))
tmp <- as.h2o(tmp)
tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp)
print(tmp)

#                                             ngram
# 1                               SIRET:417 653 698
# 2                         SIRET:417 653 698 00031
# 3                                            Sans
# 4                                       Sans esc.
# 5 Sans esc. jusquau\nSans esc. jusquau 15.11.2018
```

There is no error message, but as you can see, we started with 6 rows, and only 5 are left in the final output.

The last 2 ones have been merged.

It's a huge issue for my current project since it basically deletes half of the rows of my data. I have isolated this example, but there are many others. From the other examples I have seen (not a lot), the quotes are always involved.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug and I don't have a work-around right now.  I have tagged it to be fixed in the next fix/minor release: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-6745